# Differentiation under the integral sign and counting measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives, power-series

Consider a power series $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$, and assume that $\displaystyle R=\lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ exists.

Use differentiation under the integral sign to show that $f(x)$ is differentiable on $(-R,R)$ with derivative $f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}$. Hint: interpret this sum as an integral with respect to counting measure.

I am confused with this hint. How can I interpret this sum as an integral and what is counting measure?

Comment: Do you know the basic theory of measures? In your case, the measure $\mu$ is defined on the set $\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ by $\mu(A) = |A| = \mathrm{card}(A)$. Thus $\mu(\{n\}) = 1$ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N}$. The limit $R$ is the radius of convergence (we require $R > 0$), and in particular $f(x) < \infty$ whenever $x \in (-R,R)$. If you define $g(x,n) = a_n x^n$, for each $x \in (-R,R)$, $g$ is continuous in $n$, and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n = \int_{\mathbb{N}} g(x,n) d\mu(n).$ Now $d/dx$ and use some form of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign .

Answer (score 2):

***The "sophisticated" solution:***

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$$
Here the sum is interpreted as the integral with respect to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \delta_n$ of the function
$$
F(n,x) = a_n x^n
$$

Hence **if** we can apply the derivation theorem:
$$
f'(x) = \frac d{dx} \sum_{n=1}^\infty F(n,x) \color{red}= 
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac d{dx}F(n,x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}
$$

Now for the justification of the red '=' sign:
you have to check that, for example on $K=\left[-|x|,|x| \right]$ (on a compact subset of $(-R,R)$ containing $x$):
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sup_{x\in K} \left|\frac d{dx}F(n,x) \right| < \infty
$$
In this case, the sum is:
$$
=  \sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n |x|^{n-1}
$$

and this sum is finite as the radius of $
\sum na_nx^{n-1}
$
is also $R$.

---

***One "elementary" solution:***

Let $x\in (-R,R)$. The convergence of the series is uniform on $[0,x]$ (because $R$ is the radius of convergence of the series, and $[-x,x]$ is a compact subset of $(-R,R)$). Hence:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^x na_n t^{n-1} dt
= \int_0^x \sum_{n=1}^\infty  na_n t^{n-1} dt
$$
and then $f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty  na_n x^{n-1}$.